# How to configure Detox lifecycle hooks in the latest version?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I run `detox` in version `17.13.2` with `jest-circus` as the test runner. My main problem is the app is not reset either after or before I run the tests which leads to an inconsistent state of the app.

My test file:

```
import { by, device, element, expect, waitFor } from "detox"

describe("Login", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative()
  })

  it("should login with correct data", async () => {
    await element(by.id("login_email_input")).typeText("mail@example.com")
    await element(by.id("login_password_input")).typeText("12345678")
    await element(by.id("login_submit_button")).tap()

    await waitFor(element(by.id("workout_screen"))).toBeVisible()

    // additional test steps

  })
})
```

Now if the login actually works but the test fails at one of the subsequent steps, the state of the app user will still be "logged in".

From what I understand, it's not possible to actually alter the app state, e.g. by clearing the `AsyncStorage` or interacting directly with the state mgmt tool. Instead, it's recommended to just reinstall the app - but this is exactly where I am struggling.

I have tried numerous approaches and none of them worked. What makes it really hard to understand [configuration is that detox completely changed how the configuration works](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/detox-in-2020-e34525548123) and switched to `jest-circus` as the main test runner.

My setup is basically the one created by `jest init -r jest`. From what I understand, this already includes some defaults for `detox.init()` and `detox.cleanup()`:

```
{
  "detox": {
    "behavior": {
      "init": {
        "reinstallApp": true,
        "launchApp": true,
        "exposeGlobals": true
      },
      "cleanup": {
        "shutdownDevice": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this does not seem to be sufficient to actually wipe the app state after running the tests.

I tried working with an init script as `setupFilesAfterEnv`, which would call `cleanup()` after the test suite is run. Actually that works in an older project which still uses `jasmine 2` as test runner.

```
import { cleanup, init } from 'detox';
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');
const specReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/specReporter');

const config = require('../package.json').detox;

// Set the default timeout
jest.setTimeout(120000);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);

// This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, jest only reports at file-level.
// This is strictly optional.
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await init(config, { launchApp: false });
}, 300000);

beforeEach(async () => {
  await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await cleanup();
});
```

First off, it complains that jasmine is not defined. I guess that's because actually the `adapter` in this case should be a `DetoxAdapterCircus` which it is not, even though in my config file I specify:

```
{
    "preset": "react-native",
    "testEnvironment": "./environment.ts",
    "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
    "testTimeout": 120000,
    "testRegex": "\\.e2e\\.ts$",
    "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
    "verbose": true
}
```

`"testRunner": "jest-circus/runner"`

Another idea would be to alter the `CustomDetoxEnvironment` but I do not understand how I can get access to the detox lifecycle hooks.

```
const {
  DetoxCircusEnvironment,
  SpecReporter,
  WorkerAssignReporter,
} = require("detox/runners/jest-circus")

class CustomDetoxEnvironment extends DetoxCircusEnvironment {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config)

    // should I access the hooks here now?

    // This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, Jest only reports at file-level.
    // This is strictly optional.
    this.registerListeners({
      SpecReporter,
      WorkerAssignReporter,
    })
  }
}

module.exports = CustomDetoxEnvironment
```

Tl;dr: I don't know where to put my reusable lifecycle hooks in the latest version of Detox. Also, I wonder if these custom configurations are even needed to reinstall the app and wipe the app data before each test suite.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `setupFilesAfterEnv`, but you're not supposed to call the same hooks/cleanup as before (see https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2410#issuecomment-744387707).

here's an example of our init script:

```
// init.ts
// with "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./init.ts"] in the conf

beforeAll(async () => {
  // to reset the state
  await device.clearKeychain();

  // we are launching the app manually
  await device.launchApp({
    permissions: { notifications: 'YES', location: 'inuse' },
  });

  await device.setURLBlacklist([
    // ...
  ]);
});
```